# pycharm/intellij grep console sounds

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Trying to get sounds working when an error is generated in pycharm console as I want to be notified when an error occurs. I installed grep console plugin, and while i have highlighting using background colours working for it [image: highlighting console output]

But when I set the corresponding sound as follows, it never plays. Is there only a specific format that works?: [image]

Alternatively can I be notified when a traceback is generated in pycharm console by some other method??

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the MP3 format, but **WAV** works great.